# WCF: DuplexChannelFactory timeout error

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-3.5

I'm using a DuplexChannelFactory when accessing my WCF service so that my service can use a callBackChannel to communicate back to the client.

That's all fine but I get a timeout error when creating the CallBackChannel if I do not use the channel for a period of time. I create the callBackChannel like so:

```
OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ICallBack>().MethodOnClient();
```

Does anyone know how to change the timeout to infinity and what the actually default timeout period is?

Answer (score 0):

I believe Timeout is set in Binding section
You can check deafult WCF values using WCF Service Configuration Editor (from Tools menu)